# 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

Tags: python-3.x, installation, setuptools, setup.py

I have a `setup.py` which contains the following:

```
from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements

def load_requirements(fname):
    """Turn requirements.txt into a list"""
    reqs = parse_requirements(fname, session="test")
    return [str(ir.requirement) for ir in reqs]


setup(
    name="Projectname",
    [...]
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    extras_require={
        'dev': load_requirements('./requirements/dev.txt')
        },
    install_requires=load_requirements('./requirements/prod.txt')
)
```

My `./requirements/prod.txt` looks like this:

```
-r common.txt
```

and my `./requirements/dev.txt` is similar but with some development specific packages. My `./requirements/common.txt`  contains a line to pip-install a package from a github link, like:

```
-e git://github.com/BioGeek/tta_wrapper.git@master#egg=tta_wrapper
```

However, since I added that line, the command `python setup.py build` fails with:

```
error in Projectname setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.
```

Versions of relevant packages:

```
pip                            20.2.2
setuptools                     50.0.0
```

How do I modify my `setup.py` or my requirements files to fix this?

**Edit**

After modifying my `setup.py` as shown in [the anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63688209/50065) of [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), I can confirm that `load_requirements` now turns my requirements files into a list with name@ url direct reference syntax where needed.

```
>>> load_requirements('./requirements/prod.txt')
['absl-py==0.8.1', 'GitPython==3.1.0', 'numpy==1.18.4', 'pip==20.2.2', 'protobuf==3.12.0', 'setuptools==41.0.0', 'scikit_learn==0.22', 'tensorflow_hub==0.8.0', 'importlib-metadata==1.6.1', 'keras-tuner==1.0.1', 'apache-beam==2.23.0', 'ml-metadata==0.23.0', 'pyarrow==0.17.0', 'tensorflow==2.3.0', 'tensorflow-data-validation==0.23.0', 'tensorflow-metadata==0.23.0', 'tensorflow-model-analysis==0.23.0', 'tensorflow-transform==0.23.0', 'tta_wrapper @ git://github.com/BioGeek/tta_wrapper.git@master']
```

However, now I get the following error when I run `python setup.py build`:

```
$ python setup.py build
/home/biogeek/code/programname/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:30: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
running build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 91, in <module>
    install_requires=load_requirements('./requirements/prod.txt')
  File "/home/biogeek/code/programname/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/biogeek/code/programname/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/biogeek/code/programname/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/biogeek/code/programname/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 984, in run_command
    cmd_obj = self.get_command_obj(command)
  File "/home/biogeek/code/programname/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 859, in get_command_obj
    cmd_obj = self.command_obj[command] = klass(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 57, in __init__
    raise TypeError("dist must be a Distribution instance")
TypeError: dist must be a Distribution instance
```

**Edit 2**

I finally made my installation succeed. I tried a few things, so not entirely sure what in the end resolved the issue, but I:

- downgraded `setuptools` from  `50.0.0` to `41.0.0`
- put `setuptools` as the first line in my requirements file (see [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/784#issuecomment-248008457))
- added a crude, hacky one-off function to point to the zip archive with the name @ url syntax.

```py
def _format_requirement(req):
    if str(req.requirement) == 'git://github.com/BioGeek/tta_wrapper.git@master#egg=tta_wrapper':
        return 'tta_wrapper @ https://github.com/BioGeek/tta_wrapper/archive/v0.0.1.zip'
    return str(req.requirement)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use [PEP 508 - *Dependency specification for Python Software Packages*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) requirements. `git://github.com/BioGeek/tta_wrapper.git@master#egg=tta_wrapper` is not valid syntax according to that standard.

`setuptools` does accept the [`name@ url` direct reference syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references):

```
tta_wrapper @ git://github.com/BioGeek/tta_wrapper.git
```

You can't put that in a requirements.txt file however, not *and* use the `-e` switch. The latter can only take a VCS URL or a local file path, **not** a requirement specification; see the [*Requirements File Format* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).

So you have translate between formats here. I'd check for the `is_editable` flag  on the `ParsedRequirement` objects that `parse_requirements()` produces, and alter behaviour accordingly. You'd have to parse the requirement string as a URL, pull out the `#egg=` fragment and put that at the front:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def _format_requirement(req):
    if req.is_editable:
        # parse out egg=... fragment from VCS URL
        parsed = urlparse(req.requirement)
        egg_name = parsed.fragment.partition("egg=")[-1]
        without_fragment = parsed._replace(fragment="").geturl()
        return f"{egg_name} @ {without_fragment}"
    return req.requirement

def load_requirements(fname):
    """Turn requirements.txt into a list"""
    reqs = parse_requirements(fname, session="test")
    return [_format_requirement(ir) for ir in reqs]
```

The above then turns `-e git:...#egg=tta_wrapper` into `tta_wrapper @ git:...`:

```
>>> load_requirements('./requirements/dev.txt')
['tta_wrapper @ git://github.com/BioGeek/tta_wrapper.git@master', 'black==20.08b1']
```

Comment: I can confirm that your code converts my requirements files into a list with name@ url direct reference syntax where needed. But now I get another error when I run `python setup.py build`, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there is no any github link in my requirements, but the line

```
-r common.txt
```

in `./requirements/prod.txt` caused the same error.

I've added stupid condition and now it works for me:

```py
def load_requirements(filename) -> list:
    requirements = []
    try:
        with open(filename) as req:
            requirements = [line for line in req.readlines() if  line.strip() != "-r common.txt"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return requirements
```